# Gnome 3.14: How to disable window effects

Tags: gnome-shell

Is there a way to disable the unnecessary window effects of Gnome 3.14?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Open `dconf-editor` (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and type `dconf-editor`) and uncheck `enable-animations` in :

```
org > gnome > desktop > interface
```

You can also use the following command :

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface enable-animations false
```

Comment: Thank you. Just for your information. dconf-editor couldn't be found.

Comment: If you need it in the future you can install it by running : `sudo apt-get install dconf-tools` :)

Comment: Just tried this answer out on `gnome 3.24` and it still works.

Comment: This didn't work for me.  I needed to follow @Torben advice, found here:
[link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/99874/how-do-i-turn-off-gnome-shell-activities-animations/562870#562870)

Comment: I said this and it also worked:
  sudo apt-get install dconf-editor