# gnome 3 lag in ubuntu gnome

Tags: gnome, intel-graphics

For some reason every single animation in gnome 3 lags a lot on my laptop (lenovo e330). I have tried the most recent versions of of other distros: debian, centos, antergos, fedora, opensuse, zorin, arch but they have the same performance problem with gnome. My laptop is reasonably powerful: core i3, 8gb ram and intel 3000 graphics. I have no lag whatsoever in windows 10, ubuntu with unity, any kde distro so this seems to be a gnome problem.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Although this question is 3 years old, I reason to bet that [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/654978/1698) would resolve anyone with a similar problem that is specific to GNOME 3. Some video chipset drivers just can't handle GNOME 3 animations very well.

Answer (score 0):

For the moment there is not really any solutions available since it is a know problem with the new version of Gnome.

What I experienced that makes the experience better is to install any video drivers that you might need. But if you have like in your case a integrated graphics card with intel there is not much you can do about that.

There is also some solutions that might help depending on your computer. Since the Gnome Session in Ubuntu 17.10 uses Wayland, like in my case I experiences some issues about that.

Something that you can do is to switch your Gnome Session from Wayland to XOrg by going in the login screen and Gnome XOrg in the gear menu. Here is the original [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/966709/389685).

You can also edit GDM to use XOrg instead of Wayland by uncommenting this line

```
WaylandEnable=false
```

in the configuration file

```
/etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```

The original comment is available [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966651/mouse-lagging-on-ubuntu-17-10?rq=1#comment-1551248).

An other solution is to downgrade Ubuntu to 17.04 so in that case you will not have any issue. You can also try to install an older version of Gnome.

That is all that I tried or found to help. I currently have the same issue on my laptop and even on my desktop with the Nvidia drivers installed.