# Mouse lagging on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: gnome, mouse, steam, 17.10

I have downloaded Ubuntu 17.10 recently, and I found out that if you move the cursor on the top bar the mouse is starting to lag. (especially if you open one of the tabs on the top bar, and then move you mouse across the bar).

I thought that's the only problem with the mouse, but then when I opened a game that is working on OPEN-GL, the mouse just didn't stop lagging, of course, when I closed the game, the mouse was working ok. (by the way, it happend with **every** steam game).

I was looking for an answer, but all I found is this solution [How can I get rid of mouse lag under Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763413/how-can-i-get-rid-of-mouse-lag-under-ubuntu).

**It did not happen when I used Ubuntu 17.04.**

I have Intel Core i5-6198DU CPU @ 2.30GHz x 4, Intel HD Graphics 510(Skylake GT1), GNOME 3.26.1, 64-bit.

Can you please help me find a solution? Thank you very much :)

Comment: So let me ask this you have mouse lag happen in 17.10 which did not happen as you used 17.10? Confuses me :)

Comment: @Videonauth I am really sorry i'll fix it right now

Comment: Don't worry, just thought I'd let you know and simply assuming that it is meant to be 17.04 was a bit far fetched for doing the edit myself. :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

*"Gnome/Wayland has mouse tracking issues (see https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=745032)."*

Ubuntu 17.10 uses wayland by default. however, you can switch back to Xorg, without to install anything, all you need to do is:

1. **Log out** from you current user.
2. Under the password, near the "unlock" button, you will have something like a settings-icon.
3. **Click it**, and choose the second option(the one says "xorg")
4. And there you have it! the good old xorg session, with **no more cursor lags!**

"*Switching to an Xorg session from the log in screen should solve it.*"

Comment: Looks like GDM3 is using Wayland by default too.  I  also needed to disable Wayland in GDM by uncommenting the `WaylandEnable=false` in `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf`

Comment: This solution doesn't work. It didn't work for me, and many others, as you see in the answers of:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/966954/ubuntu-17-10-tons-of-lags-with-mouse-and-window-glitch  (It appears to be a genuine problem with Gnome & an unresolved bug as of now)

Comment: @LovesProbability This mouse lag issue is widely known and specifically relates to Wayland. The general lag is a separate issue and not being asked by this question.

Comment: I'm using xorg and the nvidia driver and definitely seeing the same lag issule. It seems to be a gnome problem, not a wayland problem.

Comment: Great job on this. My guess would be that *Gnome* these days basically requires that your video card have a GPU. Otherwise (as everyone has reported), the mouse and keyboard lag render Ubuntu completely unusable. Such was the case with my otherwise-screaming 32GB 8-way server--since it still has a 'dumb' raster buffer (CPU-access only) video card.

Answer (score -1):

Just sharing my case.

My laptop : i7(kabylake) + HD620 graphics card. I read that usually its the driver's problem. so,

Installed Intel HD620 graphics driver, and mouse lagging was solved. Intel driver currently only support 17.04. So I followed below answer.

[How to Install the latest Intel Graphics Driver in Ubuntu 17.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/980203/how-to-install-the-latest-intel-graphics-driver-in-ubuntu-17-10)

(edited following the advice)

Basically,

- Backup and edit your `/etc/lsb-release` file to fool the installer.
- Download and install Intel driver.
- Change `/etc/lsb-release` back to original.

But, mouse lagging still happens when I use Transmission(torrent client) downloading about 5 files. other than that, looks good.

Another thing is by installing the graphics driver, it solved the problem of a blank tool tip when moused over anything first time, so I had to put mouse over repeatedly, but it's now solved too.