# Ubuntu 18.04 gnome-shell processes slowing down system

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell

After running Ubuntu 18.04 for some days without logging out, things has started to get slower and slower. When I try to switch windows, it can take 5-10 seconds before anything happens. The same when trying to activate a window or text field for giving keyboard input. I opened a terminal window and ran `top` and watched the output for some minutes. In general, three processes stays on the top of the list: 1) gnome-shell (8% cpu), 2) chrome (6% cpu), and 3) Xorg (4% cpu):

[image]

These number does not change very much (± 1% ) while I am watching.

I did not have this problem in 17.04, however it appeared in 17.10, but only for the first few weeks I think. Then suddenly everything worked as normal. But now after upgrading to 18.04, the problem has returned.

See also [Ubuntu 17.10 tons of lags with mouse and window glitch](https://askubuntu.com/q/966954/156688)

Comment: Just drop it and change to normal desktop (Xfce, Cinnamon, MATE are good examples).

Comment: Same problem, here. The issue seems to be with the graphical interface since after logging out and in again (without rebooting) solves the problem.... temporarily! Also, the problem appears with both Nvidia and X.Org drivers, and with the all the three default choices in the login screen (Ubuntu / Ubuntu Wayland / Classic). It would be really appreciated any help to understand what is causing this nasty behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon the command `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`. Seems it may have been the problem with nvidia drivers in my case, after that the gnome-shell cpu behavior was back to normal