# why is my Ubuntu 18.04 lagging? And there is also difficulty using mouse, it is not smooth

Tags: system-installation, 18.04

I just upgraded my existing version to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS but now I am having lagging issues with my mouse.  It is moving in a sluggish way, where it takes time to accelerate, and takes time to stop too, making it difficult to do fine movement and e.g. click on small buttons on the screen.

I want to know how to make my mouse more responsive again, like it used to be in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question with your hardware details? It might happen due to a GPU driver, for example.

Comment: Try switching to Xorg as described here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/966651/mouse-lagging-on-ubuntu-17-10

Comment: I have the same problem, switching workspaces is kinga laggy too. We might have to wait until the release of 18.04.1 that should happen a month after the release of 18.04

Comment: @stephan-henningsen: If you think you have the answer to this question think again, because there's very little info to go by. Of course you're always welcome to write your own question with a more detailed issue description and [answer it yourself](/help/self-answer). If you want you can then post a link to your question in the comment section of this one. Although its author didn't log in since they posted their question and it's likely going to be locked and deleted automatically for inactivity.